# How to bound the service, JobService, with firebase jobdispatcher

Tags: android, firebase-job-dispatcher

I want to update my UI component like the textview, but localbinder, onbind, onStartCommand are final of the jobservice in jodispatcher library so that I can implement the bound service in my activity just as below code:

```
    /** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                IBinder service) {
            // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
            LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };
```

Comment: I'm working on the same thing. Have you found any solution?